# How to write on an icon in kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, marker

I want to add Icons to googlemaps as markers and then want to write a number over them. Because I want to implement a lot of the icon marker and most need a different number to be displayed and it would be too inefficient to make so many different icons beforehand. Has anyone an idea how I can accomplish that?

Comment: You can generate a bitmap on the fly with the different numbers using bitmap 
and canvas operations. Android canvases include a Canvas.drawText function that may help. Check out something like this: https://android.okhelp.cz/create-bitmap-and-draw-text-into-bitmap-android-example/

Comment: thank you Felix Guo, would you happen to know how I can implement that in google maps? because I have to addmarker(..).addicon where I need to add the bitmap with the path

Comment: You can create a Bitmap object based on a resource using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` which will give you the base. Then you can bind it to a `Canvas` and use `Canvas.drawText` to draw the number you want on top of the base image. Then you can just use something like: `marker...icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapHere))` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#customize_the_marker_image